# Change height of ui:inputSelect

Tags: lightning-aura-components, ui-inputselect

I am successfully using the following code to collect a user's multiple input selections.  I don't like how the select box is a certain height regardless of the # of options displayed.  I would like to alter the height of the input box.  Ideally I would do this based on the # of options available, but just being able to make it shorter will be sufficient.  Thoughts?

```
        <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
        <ui:inputSelect aura:id="filterByOrganization"
                        class="multiple"
                        multiple="true"
                        value="{!v.selection}"
                        change="{!c.selectOrganization}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.values}" var="item">
                <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!item.key}"
                                      label="{!item.value}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ui:inputSelect>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
```

Comment: ui:inputSelect is deprecated please use the lightning:select

Answer (score 1):

got its style from HTML you need to use important in CSS to override is below is the example

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <ui:inputSelect class="single" aura:id="InputSelectSingle" change="{!c.onSingleSelectChange}">

            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Any"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Open" value="true"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Closed"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Closed Won"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Prospecting"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Qualification"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Needs Analysis"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Closed Lost"/>
    </ui:inputSelect>
</aura:application>
```

and the CSS

```
.THIS.single{
    height : 50px !important;
}
```

Please let me know if you are looking for this. **UI:#** elements are deprecated so please do not use unless no other options are available.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for lightning:select, it doesn't support multiselect, so I'm wondering with ui elements being deprecated what the intended choice would be within Aura

Comment: When I look at Chrome's Developer's tools, I see that there is a Size option that is set to 7.  I can change that in the Developer's tools and can adjust the number of select options that display.  However, when I try to set that option in my component, I receive a message that it is an invalid attribute.

Comment: @Avijit Chakraborty  I needed to put a space between .THIS and .MULTIPLE to get the CSS height option to work.  There seems like there should be a way to set the # of rows that display in a inputSelect.  When I look at the code in the Chrome developer's tools, I see that there is a size="7" option.  I can change it in the developer tools.  I can't see a way to change it in Salesforce.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As as alternative to ui:inputSelect you can use lightning:dualListbox for building multi select picklist. lightning:dualListbox component has size attribute that can be used to control the height of the component based on number of options available.

```
<aura:attribute name ="len" type="integer" default="2"/>

<lightning:dualListbox name="languages"
                           label= "Select Languages"
                           sourceLabel="Available"
                           selectedLabel="Selected"
                           fieldLevelHelp="Select your preferred languages"
                           options="{!v.options}"
                           size="{!v.len}"/>
```

lightning:dualListbox documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox/specification

in case, dualListBox is not the one you want as per the UI design, then maybe you can use HTML select and options tag. 
I tried that in my dev org and the size can be set from an aura:attribute but working with selected elements from this select element will be adding complexity.